# Find the number of carry operations needed to add two numbers digit by digit

Tags: javascript, interview-questions

I don't know if my test cases at the bottom cover every case, or if my mathematical logic in the reducer function is exactly right (referring to the math that starts with `(d1 + d2 >= 10)`). More importantly I'm uncomfortable with the readability of this code as it's rather compact and difficult to parse, so any feedback is appreciated!

(As an afterthought, I'm also not sure how this would scale if the question simply changed from adding two numbers to adding N numbers, since the carry digit wouldn't always be `1`.)

It would be nice if all functions were one-liners, also. Two of them aren't.

````js
/***
 * Problem Statement:
 * Given two numbers `n1` and `n2`, write a function that returns 
 * the number of carry operations required to add them digit-by-digit,
 * similar to pen-and-paper arithmetic with a `1` being carried as
 * the digits are added column-wise right-to-left, like this:
 * 
 *      49
 *    + 55
 *    ----
 *     104
 * 
 * The right-most column is 9+5=14, which is two digits,
 *      so we carry the `1` and write `4`. That's a carry operation.
 * 
 * The left-most column is 4+5=9, but we add the carried `1`,
 *      so we write `10` before `4`. I don't know if this is a carry or not, but I assume not.
 * 
 * In the end, we wrote `104`, and a single carry operation happened,
 *      so `f(49, 55)` is `1`. Arguably the answer is `2`.
 * 
 * More tests are below.
 */

 // Here's my solution in JavaScript which is O(n):

 // Helper functions:

 const indexes = arr => arr.map((_, i) => i);

 const getDigits = n => n.toString().split('').map(Number);

 const getArithmeticRows = (n1, n2) =>
    [n1, n2].map(n => getDigits(n).reverse());

 /***
  * `f(n1, n2)` takes two integers and returns the integer number
  * of carries required to add `n1` and `n2`.
  */
 const numberOfCarryOperations = (n1, n2) => {
    const rows = getArithmeticRows(n1, n2), [row1, row2] = rows;
    return ((row1.length > row2.length)
        ? indexes(row1) : indexes(row2))
        .reduce((partialCarry, _, i) => {
            const [d1, d2] = rows.map(row => row[i] || 0);
            return partialCarry + (
                ((d1 + d2 >= 10)
                || (d1 === 9 && partialCarry !== 0)
                || (d2 === 9 && partialCarry !== 0))
                ? 1 : 0
            );
        }, 0);
};

// Tests:

console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(44, 56)); // pass (1)
console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(9999, 1)); // pass (4)
console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(1, 9999)); // pass (4)
console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(55, 49)); // pass (1)
console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(50, 49)); // pass (0)
console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(12345, 4)); // pass (0)
console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(31, 24)); // pass (0)
console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(56799, 5)); // pass (2)
console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(6, 99999)); // pass (5)
console.log(numberOfCarryOperations(66, 99999)); // pass (5)
```
````

Comment: There is a neat mathematical way. Number of carry operations when adding `x` and `y` in base `b` can be calculated using `(s(x) + s(y) - s(x+y)) / (b-1)` where `s(n)` is the sum of digits of `n` in base `b`, which is simply `n%b + s(n/b)` if `n>0` and `0` when `n==0`. - *This is because when a carry occurs, the current digit decreases by `b` and the next one increases by `1`, which is a change of `(b-1)` in the sum of digits.*